# Android: Finish activity when SlidingMenu (jfeinstein) is showing

Tags: android, android-fragments, back-button, slidingmenu

I'm trying to implement the sliding menu created by jfeinstein in my app. The behavior I want to achieve is that when I press the back button and the menu is not showing, it will show up. This works great.
However when the menu is showing pressing the back button should finish the current activity. What happens instead is that the sliding menu is just closed again.

To achieve the described behavior I have overwritten onBackPressed:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
    SlidingMenu sm = getSlidingMenu();
    if(!sm.isMenuShowing())
    {
        sm.showMenu();
    }
    else
    {
        finish();
    }
}
```

But as soon as the sliding menu is showing onBackPressed isn't called anymore. I suspect as I have to use a SlidingFragmentActivity pressing the back button triggers the fragment history stack to pops.

Does anybody know how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After browsing the SlidingMenu code a little further I found that onKeyUp is overwritten in SlidingFragmentActivity. So the way to go is to override onKeyUp in your activity.

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
{
    if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)
    {
        SlidingMenu sm = getSlidingMenu();
        if(sm.isMenuShowing())
        {
            finish();
            return true;
        }
    }
    return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event);
}
```